# Visual Studio is erroneously giving target .NET Framework not installed message

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

My computer's operating system is Windows 11 Pro.

The latest .NET Framework version on it is 4.8.9032.0. I confirmed it by using File Explorer:

- Open C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework folder. Inside it, the folder with latest version is v4.0.30319.
- Open v4.0.30319 folder and select Accessibility.dll file.
- Open its properties, then open Details tab and in there the value of Product version is 4.8.9032.0

I have Visual Studio 2019 Community installed.

I download a C# class project whose target .NET Framework version is v4.8.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

When I try to open it in Visual Studio 2019, I get an error message:

> The C# project "Abc" is targeting ".NETFramework,Version=v4.8", which is not installed on this machine.

But this is not true as the computer has 4.8 version installed. Why I am getting this error message?

Comment: That is not what it is complaining about, it can't find the developer pack for 4.8.  Reference assemblies.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers

Comment: @HansPassant When I install Visual Studio 2019, is developer pack for latest version not install automatically?

Comment: 4.8 shipped after VS2019 was released.  So no.

Comment: I would publish you app and install on deploy machine using setup.exe that is created with publishing.

Comment: If you don't want to install additional .net framework 4.8, you can use Visual Studio 2022 directly. Visual Studio 2022 has better compatibility with .net framework 4.8